# NullPointerException in compiler when making play framework 2.2.2 project in idea 13.1.1

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework-2.2

Import procedure:

go to the samples/java/computer-database folder of play distribution, run command: 
play idea

go to idea and import the project.

when I try to 'make' the project (Build > Make Project) the following error is displayed and the make process gets stuck:

```
    Error:Play 2 Compiler:  java.lang.NullPointerException
    Error:Play 2 Compiler:  Use 'last' for the full log.
```

I have idea 13.1.1 with play 2.0 support plugin(0.33.412) and play framework 2.2.2

Comment: you don't "make" the project. It compiles automatically when you make changes. You simply have to refresh the browser.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I know it is compiled by the console, but in order for ide to load changes (like template compiled classes) I should make the project (?)

Comment: no, you shouldn't do any make and compile stuff inside IDE. Just do your changes and save the file and the rest is taken care by Play itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some try and error and studying Play and Scala plugins' compatibility issues, I worked around this problem by downgrading Scala and Play plugins to 0.33.393 (both).

Note that I still needed to add target/scala-2.10/src_managed/main to sources of the module.